# How do I Make a run block action Swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hi I have been trying to do this for a long time,I am using Swift SpriteKit , my problem is that I need to make a  runBlock action for a node how do I make an action which runs a function I have tried this:

```
        var a = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawn1()})
```

For your information The spawn1 is the function.
Thanks in advance!

Heres my code for help of the comment of the first answer:

```
//
//  PlaysScene.swift
//  Pocket Rocket3
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 27/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lucas Farleigh. All rights reserved.
//

import spriteKit

class PlayScene:SKScene {
    //declaring the node in this scene!
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

    let bar1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar1")

    let bar2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar2")

    let bar3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar3")

    let bar4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar4")

    let bar5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar5")

    let bar6a = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6b = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar6c = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6d = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar6e = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6f = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar6g = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6h = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")

    let bar6i = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    let bar6j = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bar6")
    //making actions

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        var actionmove = SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 15)
        var delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1.5))
        var delchild = SKAction.removeFromParent()

        func spawn1(){
            bar6a.position = CGPointMake(800 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6b.position = CGPointMake(1600,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            addChild(bar6a)
            addChild(bar6b)


        }
        func spawn2 (){
            bar6c.position = CGPointMake(400 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6d.position = CGPointMake(1200,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            addChild(bar6c)
            addChild(bar6d)


        }
        func spawn3 (){
            bar6e.position = CGPointMake(600 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6f.position = CGPointMake(1400,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            addChild(bar6e)
            addChild(bar6f)


        }
        func spawn4 (){
            bar6g.position = CGPointMake(700 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6h.position = CGPointMake(1500,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            addChild(bar6g)
            addChild(bar6h)


        }

        func spawn5 (){
            bar6i.position = CGPointMake(700 ,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            bar6j.position = CGPointMake(1500,CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
            addChild(bar6i)
            addChild(bar6j)


        }
        var a = SKAction.runBlock({ self.spawn1() })
        var b = SKAction.runBlock(spawn2)
        var c = SKAction.runBlock(spawn3)
        var d = SKAction.runBlock(spawn4)
        var e = SKAction.runBlock(spawn5)



        var delayA = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(1.5))
        var delayB = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2))
        var delayC = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(4))
        var delayD = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(6))
        var delayE = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(8))

        var sequence1 = SKAction.sequence([delayA,a,actionmove,delchild])
        var sequence2 = SKAction.sequence([delayB,b,actionmove,delchild])
        var sequence3 = SKAction.sequence([delayC,c,actionmove,delchild])
        var sequence4 = SKAction.sequence([delayD,d,actionmove,delchild])
        var sequence5 = SKAction.sequence([delayE,e,actionmove,delchild])

        var repeat1 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence1)
        var repeat2 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence2)
        var repeat3 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence3)
        var repeat4 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence4)
        var repeat5 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence5)


        //actionmove: making it smooth
        actionmove.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut

        //doing stuff with the background
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
       background.yScale = 10.0
        background.xScale = 10.0

        addChild(background)

        //running the actions
        bar6a.runAction(repeat1)
        bar6b.runAction(repeat1)
        bar6c.runAction(repeat2)
        bar6d.runAction(repeat2)
        bar6e.runAction(repeat3)
        bar6f.runAction(repeat3)
        bar6g.runAction(repeat4)
        bar6h.runAction(repeat4)
        bar6i.runAction(repeat5)
        bar6j.runAction(repeat5)



    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



    }
}
```

Comment: you put all your functions *inside* the didMoveToView function, therefore they are not accessible by writing self.spawn1() because they aren't functions of the class but local functions only accessible from within didMoveToView. If that isn't the issue post the error message(s) you get.

Comment: Wait I have a problem when i move them out of didMoveToView() and run it it goes to app delegate and said Thread 1: signal SAGRBT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = SKAction.runBlock({ self.spawn1() })
yournode.runAction(a)
```

Comment: I did this but on the line you gave me it gives an error that says "Playscene does not have a member named 'spawn1'" My code is  edited so you can see all of my code.

Comment: like LearnCocos2D said.  you are putting your functions inside other functions so they arent callable.  Put them directly in the body of your class.